# Is there a way to analyze PHP5.x code using PHP7.x rules and standards?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, php-5.3, php-7.0

Our current Development and Production systems are PHP v5.3.10/Ubuntu 12.04 environment. We Our new environment will be PHP Version 7.0.30/Ubuntu 16.04.

Is there a way to analyze our current PHP5.3 code and determine the scope of how much work would be needed once we port current code into our new PHP7.0 environment?

This will help give us a feel for how much work will be required to migrate from PHP5.3 to PHP7.0.

Comment: Doesn't the official doc cover all the questions about deprecated functions? http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

Comment: What do you recommend, then? Here, I *need* an opinion? I am not otherwise finding opinions out there, which is why I posted it here. Also, do you have an opinion you can share?

Comment: @dcparham Asking for opinions and recommendations is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: ok ok, but where to go for opinions, then? anyway, Unholy, thx for mentioning it, but no, the official doc does not cover the mssql_ functions, for example. One would think php.net would have a 1-stop-shop page listing all the deprecated features and functions. seems like a pretty simple concept to post online.

Comment: @dcparham `mssql` is clearly listed as a removed extension here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance is the big plus in PHP7, but the effort to migrate to it depends from your time/money and the traffic in the website, if it is heavy you should consider the migration as a real option.

For security reasons, maintenance, lots of important deprecated function, and the new cloud hosting services, I recommend to not use PHP5.3. Migrate to PHP5.6, can be a sooner solution for future problems. In the last days I have been experimenting hosting problems with mysql_connect(This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0) function used in PHP5.3, and this is just an example

Comment: thank you, Kenneth, that helps. our time/money is sparse, and website traffic is fixed. from what i've gathered so far, we've decided to keep Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS and maybe upgrade to PHP5.6.